# How can I translate the expression "sour grapes" to Spanish?

Tags: traducción, modismos

From the [Oxford dictionary:](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sour?q=sour%20grapes#sour__12)

> **sour grapes**
>
> used to refer to an attitude in which someone adopts a negative attitude to something because they cannot have it themselves:
>
> *government officials dismissed many of the complaints as sour grapes*

Is there an equivalent or similar expression in Spanish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The precise translation may vary depending on the context, but *envidia* captures the meaning of *sour grapes*; take a look at the definition according to the DRAE:

> envidia.
>
> (Del lat. invidĭa).
>
> 1. f. Tristeza o pesar del bien ajeno.
> 2. f. Emulación, deseo de algo que no se posee.

In your concrete example, I would say something like:

> Los representantes del gobierno rechazaron la mayoría de las quejas por considerarlas producto de la envidia.

Answer (score 4):

My Larousse Gran Diccionario translates it this way:

> IDIOM **it's (a case of) sour grapes** es cuestión de despecho

So there may not be an equivalent idiom, or at least not a widely used one.

Comment: Despecho is usually used more in love affairs though it could apply to any other areas (but quite unusual). If I hear "ella está despechada" I would think automatically that she had problems with love.

Comment: I't always good to learn about the limits of your dictionaries!

Answer (score 3):

Apart from "envidia" given by Gonzalo Medina, maybe "**frustración**" can also match the meaning:

> El gobierno desestimó muchas de las quejas por ser producto de la frustración.

Answer (score 1):

There is an Esopo's fable about the fox that passes by a grape vine. There were a bunch of grapes that looked simply delicious... and the fox was hungry. So he jumped and jumped trying to get them, effortlessly. Finally he gave up saying: "They are not ripe yet!". In Spanish the fox said: "¡Están verdes!", or very well could have said "Sour grapes!"

So this could be a good translation: "Están verdes". However, even though valid and used, it's not really widely used.

Answer (score 0):

I think this idiom comes from the Aesop's fable The Fox and the Grapes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fox_and_the_Grapes. Thus, the most exact (but not necessarily the best) translation would be "uvas verdes", which refers to the same frustration feeling. Please note that it is not a spanish expression in common use.

Answer (score -1):

Could you say *¡qué envidia!* (like you all would say *¡qué lastima!*), or something like that?